# setInfoWindowAdapter is not refreshing in for() loop

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps, maps

I'm parsing JSON from server response and put markers to Google Maps V2 on Android. To display snippet i'm using custom layout with HTML code. My problem that markers are putting correctly but `setInfoWindowAdapter` are get data only from first JSON element and then not refreshing, so i get the same information when click on any of markers. Here is my function:

```
void createMarkersFromJson(String json) throws JSONException {
    // De-serialize the JSON string into an array of city objects
    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    jsonArray = jObj.getJSONArray("my_array");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        // Create a marker for each city in the JSON data.

        JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        time = new Date(jsonObj.getInt("time"));
        calendar.setTime(time);

        htmlString =
                "<div>\n" +
                "            <b>"+jsonObj.getString("name")+"</b>\n" +
                "            <span> - </span>\n" +
                "            <small>\n" +
                "                <a href='http://www.foo.bar/' target='_blank' title='FooBar'>" + "# " +
        jsonObj.getInt("id")+"</a>\n" +
                "            </small>\n" +
                "        </div>\n" +
                "        <div>\n" +
                        getString(R.string.dissapear) + " " + calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR)+":"+calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+":"+calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND)+"\n</div>\n";
        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window_layout, null);
                Spanned spannedContent = Html.fromHtml(htmlString);
                TextView html = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.html);
                html.setText(spannedContent, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
                return v;
            }
        });
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(new LatLng(
                        jsonObj.getDouble("latitude"),
                        jsonObj.getDouble("longitude")));
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromAsset("icons/"+jsonObj.getString("id")+".png"));
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    }
    Log.e(JSON_TAG, "JSON sucessfully parsed");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window_layout, null);
            Spanned spannedContent = Html.fromHtml(htmlString);
            TextView html = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.html);
            html.setText(spannedContent, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
            return v;
        }
```

Map can only have one InfoWindowAdapter. You are using it as if there were one for each marker.
So, in the above method, no matter what is the marker passed by parameter, you are always using the same string.

In order to achieve what you want, you should build the string for each marker, and set the InfoWindowAdapter at the end.
Like this:

```
Map<Marker, String> markers = new HashMap<Marker, String>();

void createMarkersFromJson(String json) throws JSONException {
    // De-serialize the JSON string into an array of city objects
    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    jsonArray = jObj.getJSONArray("my_array");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        // Create a marker for each city in the JSON data.
        JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        time = new Date(jsonObj.getInt("time"));
        calendar.setTime(time);

        htmlString =
                "<div>\n" +
                "            <b>"+jsonObj.getString("name")+"</b>\n" +
                "            <span> - </span>\n" +
                "            <small>\n" +
                "                <a href='http://www.foo.bar/' target='_blank' title='FooBar'>" + "# " +
        jsonObj.getInt("id")+"</a>\n" +
                "            </small>\n" +
                "        </div>\n" +
                "        <div>\n" +
                        getString(R.string.dissapear) + " " + calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR)+":"+calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+":"+calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND)+"\n</div>\n";

        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(new LatLng(
                        jsonObj.getDouble("latitude"),
                        jsonObj.getDouble("longitude")));
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromAsset("icons/"+jsonObj.getString("id")+".png"));
        Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        markers.put(marker, htmlString);
    }

        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window_layout, null);
                Spanned spannedContent = Html.fromHtml(markers.get(marker));
                TextView html = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.html);
                html.setText(spannedContent, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
                return v;
            }
        });
    Log.e(JSON_TAG, "JSON sucessfully parsed");
}
```

Comment: Wow, this was really above my java skills. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)